# reading CSV in C when the table is broken

Tags: c, csv, file-handling

here is my C code to read CSV file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct record
{long a,b,c;    };

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "b.csv";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        char line [ 80 ];
        struct record record [ 50 ];
        size_t count, i = 0;

        while ( i < sizeof record / sizeof *record )
        {
            if ( fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL )
            {
                break;
            }

            if ( sscanf(line, "%ld,%ld,%ld", &record[i].a,&record[i].b,&record[i].c) == 3 )
            {
                ++i;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);

        for ( count = i, i = 0; i < count; ++i )
        {
            printf("record[%lu]: a = %ld b = %ld c = %ld\n",
                (long unsigned)i, record[i].a, record[i].b,record[i].c);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        perror(filename);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

/* file.csv

```
301,36,15
302,88,75
```

*/
/* my output

```
record[0]: a = 301 b = 36 c = 15
record[1]: a = 302 b = 88 c = 75
```

*/

I have 2 issues with above code..

1st issue is :
/* file.csv

```
 301,,15
 302,88,
 ,,,34
```

The output should be

```
record[0]: a = 301 b = 0 c = 15
record[1]: a = 302 b = 88 c = 0
record[2]: a = 0 b = 0 c = 34
```

and the 2nd issue is it should read file until “eof”. here I have taken 50 as a static line number value. what changes I should make ?

see I have changed code at this way...

```
  const char* getfield(char* line, int num) {
        const char* tok;
        for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
                tok && *tok;
                tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
        {
            if (!--num)
                return tok;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE* stream = fopen("b.csv", "r");
        char line[1024];
        char *pstr;int num;
         const char* value;

        while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
        {
            char* tmp = strdup(line);
        //printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));    
        value=getfield(tmp, 3);
        num =strtol(value,&pstr,10);
        printf("Field 3 would be %d\n", num);
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: consider return value of sscanf means how many actual assigments are done and accordingly put into data member

Comment: You can also read a line and apply strtok on comma and if value then put into data

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the

```
sscanf(line, "%ld,%ld,%ld", &record[i].a,&record[i].b,&record[i].c)
```

line, you can use the `strtok_r()` function ([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok_r.html)) for splitting the line into comma-separated substrings. Then on each substring, either perform an `strtol()` call ([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html)) to obtain its integer value, or set the corresponding variable to `0` if it's an empty string.

You can check for an empty string using

```
if (str[0] == 0) {
    // empty
}
```

For reading until `EOF`, simply check for `fgets()` returning `NULL` and also check `if (feof(file))` - if the end of file is reached, `fgets()` sets the EOF indicator of the `FILE *` stream, and returns `NULL`.

Comment: strtok  gives segfault at NULL value checking.. can you please write full method of NULL value handling..

Comment: @user95711 no, sorry. You have to make some effort yourself.

Comment: I have tried but when if found "123, ,110"  it is treating 110 as a second data !!! and third is still null. if I use "strtol" at a null point it gives segfault. otherwise It prints NULL

Comment: printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));  if i "un comment" this line and "comment" below three it is not giving segfault.. here the another issue is if i write  1st and 3rd  data is considering 3rd as a second. and the third is still NULL, which causes "segfault"

Comment: @user95711 you're misusing "strtok". You should use `","` as the separator, not `",\n"`.

Comment: my m istake..."strtol" is giving "segfault" not strtok

Comment: @user95711 I see, and that doesn't really change the scenario. That segfaults because `strtok()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: so have you any idea how can I make it return 0,when it found null ? I have tried but could not solve it